# Asymmetry of the indices in a Weyl transformation for the Polyakov action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

The Polyakov action
$${\mathcal {S}}={T \over 2}\int \mathrm {d} ^{2}\sigma {\sqrt {-h}}h^{ab}g_{\mu \nu }(X)\partial _{a}X^{\mu }(\sigma )\partial _{b}X^{\nu }(\sigma )$$
is invariant under the transformation
$$h_{ab} \to e^{2\omega(\sigma,\tau)} h_{ab}$$
this can be seen eaily since under the above transformation $h^{ab} \to e^{-2\omega(\sigma,\tau)} h^{ab}$ and $\sqrt{-h}\to \sqrt{e^{2\omega(\sigma,\tau)}}\sqrt{-h}$

but let me rewrite the action as
$${\mathcal {S}}={T \over 2}\int \mathrm {d} ^{2}\sigma {\sqrt {-h}}h_{ab}g_{\mu \nu }(X)\partial ^{a}X^{\mu }(\sigma )\partial ^{b}X^{\nu }(\sigma )$$

then it no longer looks Weyl invariant.

So, my question is why is it that **we keep** $\partial _{a}X^{\mu }$ **unchanged** but we **change** $\partial ^{a}X^{\mu }$? Is it just a **convention**? Or is $\partial _{a}X^{\mu }$ **more fundamental** than $\partial ^{a}X^{\mu }$?

Comment: I wrote an answer. But if anyone thinks it is wrong and there is a fundamental difference between them please write your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the asymmetry between the indices is a **convention**. We chose $\sigma^{\mu}=(\sigma, \tau)$ as the integration variables. This implies that the determinant of $h_{ab}$ will be the Jacobian. So there is an asymmetry between the upper and lower indices. Had we taken $\sigma_{\mu}$ as the integration variables then the Jacobian would be the determinant of $h^{ab}$. So, since we always take $\sigma^{\mu}$ as the integration variables, in the standard convention we **fix** $\partial _{a}X^{\mu}$.

Comment: This is also indirectly related to the fact that we prefer 
$d s^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}d x^{\mu}d x^{\nu} $ over $d s^{2}=g^{\mu\nu}d x_{\mu}d x_{\nu} $. For example, when taking the determinant of the metric.